# Problems redirecting from a 403 using .htaccess (Yourls)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-403, yourls

I'm using a php app called Yourls. It's a self-hosted url shortener and it's pretty great, I'm happy with its overall functionality. Due to the nature of its development however there isn't much in the way of support. Let's pretend the base url is af.to, where a shortened url would be af.to/goo that might redirect to whatever url is defined by 'goo'. The problem I'm facing is that if someone goes to af.to, they end up on a 403-Forbidden. I'd rather the client is redirected to a specific url instead. I have already picked up a plugin for Yourls which redirects to a url when a shortlink is not found or mis-typed, but this does not cover the base of af.to

I attempted to put in a 403 redirect in the .htaccess, but that broke the whole yourls script resulting in a 500 server error.

Current .htaccess looks like this:

```
    # BEGIN YOURLS
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /yourls-loader.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END YOURLS
```

Any help on what I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you given the appropriate MySQL access to the correct user?

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteCond blocks tell the RewriteRule to skip existing files / folders. When you go to http://af.to/, the root folder exists : no redirection. The apache server doesn't find any `index.html` (or `index.php`) file, isn't allowed to list the content of the folder, give up and returns a 403 Forbidden.

You can create the `index.html` file to show some content or you can add these lines to redirect to an other url :

```
# just after RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/$ http://my-compagny.com/ [L,R=301]
```